# Weird behavior in VS code regex search

Tags: visual-studio-code

Has anyone notice this weird behavior in vscode regex search or im using it wrongly?
The regex search in vscode is matching "space" in between the characters and when i was traversing between the matches with the arrow key it will jump from 1st match to the 3rd match etc.

text string: abcdefg
regex: [a]*

I have upload a video demonstrating the behavior

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/7134796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `[a]*` matches *zero* or more letter a's.  This means that zero width markers in between letters are also a match.  You should use `[a]+` here, which means one or more letter a's.

See the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jAtfUE/1) for the behavior you probably want.

Comment: Thanks! I understand i probably should be using [a]+ here. 
Suspected some hidden special character, but I didn’t know zero width markers, probably I shld be reading up on it.

Comment: actually i cant find any zero width unicode character. is it different from zero width markers u mentioned?